# NameError: name 'static_url' is not defined

Tags: python, django, summernote, static-files

I am trying to upgrade [django-summernote](https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote) to version 0.8.5 in my django 1.9 project, but using the settings given, I get this error:

```
 File "my_project/settings/base.py", line 314, in <module>
        static_url('django_summernote/summernote.css'),
 NameError: name 'static_url' is not defined
```

I haven't seen `static_url()` before, where did it come from and how do I get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looking at the source.  You'll see that the function `static_url` is defined in `django_summernote.settings`.

So, to use it in your settings module you'll either need to be importing it, or defining it yourself as something like:

```
def static_url(url):
    return os.path.join(STATIC_URL, url)
```

Answer (score 0):

from django.conf.urls.static_url import static_url

if you got error while using static then use this import method
[from django.conf.urls.static import static]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).